# Button tag misbehave on Firefox 26

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button

I have a form with a username and password field on it, both tagged as required, and a submit button that do some checking (running a javascript function) before submitting the form. 
The html code looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="myfunc(this.form,this.form.password) ">Sign in</button>
```

After entering the correct username and password then click the sign in button, Firefox just clear the password field and treat it as empty. Then it goes on and say i need to fill in the password field.

I have to convert the button tag to input tag for it to work properly.

```
<input type="button" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                    onclick="myfunc(this.form,this.form.password);">
```

The button tag seems to work in Safari..

I don't see the harm of using input type for the moment, but am just curious why this happen in firefox?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: If the code of `myfunc` is irrelevant, the problem should be presented as reduced so that `myfunc` is not called. If it is relevant, it should be included in the question.

Comment: `<button>` is not the same as `<input type="button">`. If you want it to work the same, give the button `type="button"` too. Otherwise, it defaults to `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem:

```
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-block" value="Submit" id="form-submit"/>
```

To **fix** it (dirty) remove the btn-block and add an inline CSS `width:100%`:

```
<input class="btn btn-lg" value="Submit" id="form-submit" style="width:100%"/>
```